# In place editing of Time object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, edit-in-place, best-in-place

I have an app, which is used to plan work shifts for a number of employees. I have a `Shift` model, where I store the `shiftstart` and the `shiftend` as `Time` objects.

I present the users `Shifts` on a page displaying several days in a table. The idea is that the user the can edit the `shiftstart` and `shiftend` directly in this table using the [Best In Place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem.

But I can't seem to figure out how to get this working when dealing with a Time object - anyone got some experience or suggestions on this.

I have the following code:

VIEW:

```
<% @myShifts.where(:shiftdate => date).order(:shiftstart).each do |shift| %>
  <div class="shift-item span">
    <div class="hider">
      <p>
        <i class="icon gear"></i>
          <%= best_in_place shift.shiftstart.strftime("%H.%M"), :type => :input %> - <%= best_in_place shift.shiftend.strftime("%H.%M"), :type => :input %>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

SCHEMA:

```
create_table "shifts", :force => true do |t|
  t.time     "shiftstart"
  t.time     "shiftend"
  t.integer  "type_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "note"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  t.date     "shiftdate"
end
```

I'm getting a "*undefined method `{:type=>:input}' for "08.00":String*" error and I already tried switching the Best In Place Type to something other the input - doesn't help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`best_in_place` method takes two mandatory arguments; an object (`shift` in you case) and a field (`shiftstart` and `shiftend`), then optional hash of options (`:type => :input`). So your code needs to be like this:

```
<%= best_in_place shift, :shiftstart, :type => :input, :display_with => Proc.new { |f| f.strftime("%H.%M") } %>
```

Comment: That gives me an error: undefined method `shift_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe659934800>:0x007fe653ce4460>.. any ideas?

Comment: Probably you're not using `ShiftsController` to handle shift's actions. You can supply your actual shift path (the one that handles PUT requests) to `best_in_place` options like this `:path => your_shift_path(shift)`. Or you can supply your `rake routes` for more insights :).

Comment: Found the problem.. my route was not right.. but your solutions seems to work.. just perfect.. :)

Comment: but do you know how to onlys show the time - ex "08:30" when in edit mode.. right now it displays a date "2000-01-01", the time and the "+100" UTC thingy :)

Comment: This is kinda hack-ish. I don't see BIP have a direct way to do it so I think you have to use JavaScript to change `data-original-content` attribute on the BIP element to the value you want to appear editable.